# Three-stage boost converter improvements

Tags: current, dc-dc-converter, ltspice, boost

Here is a three-stage boost converter that I simulated in LTSpice.

I am getting the high voltage output that I desire (1.3 kV). Before I proceed to the design phase, I would like to discuss a few things.

**My questions are the following:**

1. Are there any obvious problems with the circuit?
2. This is a single block of a larger system, if the next block of the system has a lower impedance, and I encounter a load regulation problem, is there some precautions I have to take for that?
3. I would like to deliver a higher current (3-4A) than what I have at the moment, how do I go about that?
4. What topology would be recommended if I need a feedback loop?

These are just questions of the top of my head...

Here is the design in question:

[image]

Here are some of the simulations:

**Output Voltage**

[image]

**Voltage at the first and second stages**

[image]

**The currents through the inductors**

[image]

**Load current**

[image]

Comment: Make your full amendments to your earlier question please. I have deleted this as a duplicate of your earlier question.

Comment: The other question felt resolved for me( the circuit works)... this question has a different topic ( improvement)

Comment: Your earlier question (without the presence of an answer) could have evolved into this question without doubt. In fact you partially updated that question with the graphs in this question so, there's no need for this question. Your transistors are still not suitable for the output voltage.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry, I will address the development in the other questions, I thought it is not ideal to just bulk up into the same questions. I will know for the future, 
Thanks,

Comment: @Dimitar also please see https://english.stackexchange.com/q/5987/2241

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for the future